# How to ensure an Java Array in a Map<String, Object> maintains it's type after GSON toJson and fromJson

Tags: java, arrays, json, arraylist, gson

I have a program that sends JSON through a serial port and vice versa. To not require the entire template of valid keys be sent all the time I get the client to send requests through a Map like so.

```
HashMap<String, Object> push = new HashMap<String, Object>();

push.put("Handshake", true);
push.put("Instructions", instructions);
push.put("RobotID", "1337");
```

This is then converted to JSON with the following code.

---

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String json = gson.toJson(myMap);
System.out.println(json);
```

And then the JSON is sent through the Serial connection.

The problem is, this builds this perfectly valid JSON.

```
{
  "RobotID": "1337",
  "Instructions": [
    "How to not be accidentally attacked by an autonomous robot.\n1. Don\u0027t stand in front of it.\n2. Don\u0027t try to run past it, it may catch you.\nThats it.",
    "This was a triumph, I\u0027m making a note here. Huge success..."
  ],
  "Handshake": true
}
```

Why is this a problem?

Due to the HashMap's contents being Object's I can't do much to check their Type. As such I use Object.getClass().getSimpleName(); to verify that such classes at least match by name. This works for most of the things I need, however after being converted back into a HashMap the Array objects such as the Instructions String[] appear as an ArrayList. This wouldn't be a problem if it would let me retrieve an Array of the type I require through the toArray method, yet it throws Exceptions if I try to use anything other than an Object to represent it or try to cast the resulting variable.

If you need to know how I am getting the data back into the HashMap, here.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

Type flexibleContainerMap = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType();
Map<String, Object> jsonValueStore = gson.fromJson(json, flexibleContainerMap);
String keys[] = new String[0];
keys = jsonValueStore.keySet().toArray(keys);
int i = 0;
while (i < keys.length) 
{

    SetValidate.updateValue(keys[i], jsonValueStore.get(keys[i]));
    i++;

}
```

I hope you at least get the gist of my situation here, any assistance is accepted including methods to access the data inside the Array/ArrayList. The goal is to avoid adding complexity on the Client. I'd prefer if it would be possible to get the Array to be read as an Array on the Server. If you could provide any ideas to do so that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't maintain its type, as type information is not present in json.

You can read the json using `JsonObject`/`JsonArray` etc:

```
JsonObject root = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonObject();

JsonArray instructions = root.getAsJsonArray("Instructions");
```

You could also use this on the other end to create the json, rather than HashMaps.

Comment: I'll have to look into the feasibility of this, as the content is unknown at runtime. If this is successful I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks already!

Comment: Thanks again, It tooks some effort to get it fit into the current code as I only needed it for arrays but your help was much appreciated.